# Slurm: fatal: No front end nodes defined

Tags: debian, hpc, slurm

I need to deploy a compute server on my Debian laptop . I only have my laptop, so I decided to make the host server and node on the same computer, but systemctl status slurmctld.service gives me an error:

```
● slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-03-14 17:34:39 +07; 1s ago
     Docs: man:slurmctld(8)
  Process: 11787 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmctld $SLURMCTLD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11789 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

мар 14 17:34:39 ecm systemd[1]: Starting Slurm controller daemon...
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Can't open PID file /run/slurmctld.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm slurmctld[11789]: slurmctld version 18.08.5-2 started on cluster cluster
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm systemd[1]: Started Slurm controller daemon.
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm slurmctld[11789]: No memory enforcing mechanism configured.
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm slurmctld[11789]: layouts: no layout to initialize
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm slurmctld[11789]: fatal: No front end nodes defined
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мар 14 17:34:39 ecm systemd[1]: slurmctld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My slurm.config

```
sudo nano /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf

# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
SlurmctldHost=ecm
#SlurmctldHost=
#
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
TaskPluginParam=Sched
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/builtin
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=info
#SlurmctldLogFile=
SlurmdDebug=info
#SlurmdLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=ecm NodeAddr=127.0.0.1 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ecm Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

I assume the problem is in #COMPUTE NODES, but I don 't understand what's wrong. Thank you in advance. In General, the task is to create a execution queue for a large number of high-performance tasks. I tried PBS Pro, but its installation was not successful, Slurm seemed simpler to me, it can be installed via apt and it has useful extensions. But if you know of another program that solves this problem and is easier to learn, I would be grateful if you could tell me about it.

Comment: Do you have the `slurm-wlm-emulator` package installed?

Comment: @damienfrancois , no, not installed. Why is it needed?

Comment: @damienfrancois It turns out that I have this package installed.

Comment: you should remove it ; it is used to run a simulator and overwrites the normal binaries